# In FireBase Analytics, we can't set the screen name displayed in Dashboard. I have added the logevent as follows:

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase-analytics

```
[
 FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:@"FirstScreen" 
 parameters:@{ 
  @"screen_name": @"First",
  @"screen_class": @"First"
  }
];
```

Comment: Have you turned off the auto screen reporter?

Comment: Yes, I think that was the problem. When i turned it to No, dashboard started displaying the Screen Name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:@"First" screenClass:@"First"]` in `ViewDidAppear` and then add `firebaseautomaticscreenreportingenabled` to `info.plist` as `Boolean` and set it as `NO`